# How to discover external libraries that produces Insecure HostnameVerifier Vulnerability when publish app on Google play

Tags: android, gradle, okhttp, android-security

When I publish my app on google play store, I receive next error:

> HostnameVerifier Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the
> HostnameVerifier interface. You can find more information about how
> resolve the issue in this Google Help Center article.

My app doesn't use  **HostnameVerifier** or **X509HostnameVerifier**.

I suspect that external libraries produces error.
My currently gradle is:

```
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //      Fire Base
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
//    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0'

    //      Facebook
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.38.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.37.0'

    //      Google Services
//    implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.2.7'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

    //      Rx
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.14'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'

    //      Networking (Retrofit)
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1'


    //      DI (Butter knife)
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    //      Image processing (Glide, Lottie, circular image & Image picker)
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.4'
    implementation 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:2.0.4'

    //      Others
    implementation 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.1.1'
    implementation 'me.himanshusoni.chatmessageview:chat-message-view:1.0.3'
    /*      dimen       */
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'
    //      Car Animation in Rate card
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // comment below line & its relative code in files, if you face issue while generate signed apk.
    //debugImplementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'

    //      payment gateway...
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments:card-form:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.18.1'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:8.0.0'

    /*      toasty      */
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.3.0'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'

    // Page Indicator using Recycler view
    implementation 'com.ryanjeffreybrooks:indefinitepagerindicator:1.0.9'


    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'

    //    Emoji Handle
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'

    implementation 'me.philio:pinentryview:1.0.6'
```

Comment: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7188426?hl=en  This should help